# rth moment of generalised 3 parameter beta distribution

Tags: statistics

The pdf of a 3 parameter beta distribution in $\alpha,\beta,\lambda $ is given by $$ f_X(x) = \frac{\Gamma \left( \alpha+\beta \right)\lambda^\alpha x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta - 1}}{\Gamma \left(\alpha \right)\Gamma \left(\beta \right)[1-(1-\lambda)x]^{\alpha + \beta} } \hspace{10pt} ,0 \leq x \leq 1 $$
and I am asked to derive $$ E(X^r) = \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+k)\Gamma(\alpha+r+k)(1-\lambda)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+r+k)k!} $$
I started by $E(X^r) = \int_0^1 x^r f_X(x) dx$ and then replacing $x=\frac{y}{1+y}$ I get $$ E(X^r) = \frac{\Gamma \left( \alpha+\beta \right) \lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}  \int_0^\infty y^{\alpha+r-1} (1+y)^{\alpha-1}(1+\lambda y)^{-\alpha-\beta} dy  $$
I have no idea what to do with that integral, or even if I am on the right track here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, the steps are:
$$ E(X^r) =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta) \lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \int^1_0 x^{\alpha + r - 1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}[1-(1-\lambda)x]^{-(\alpha+\beta)} dx $$
Using binomial expansion, i.e. $ (1-ax)^{-b} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{\Gamma(b + k)(ax)^k}{\Gamma(b)k!} $
the integral is rewritten as $$ E(X^r) =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta) \lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \int^1_0 x^{\alpha + r - 1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + k)(1-\lambda)^k x^k}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)k!} dx $$
Cancel out $ \Gamma(\alpha + \beta) $ and reorganize and combine terms to get $$ E(X^r) =\frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + k)(1-\lambda)^k}{k!} \int^1_0 x^{\alpha + r + k - 1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} dx  $$
Then the integral is standard Beta type I with $p=\alpha +r+k$  and $q=\beta$ so that $$ \int^1_0 x^{\alpha + r + k - 1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} dx = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+r+k)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta + r + k)} $$
Plugging this in, you get the desired result.